# How to construct a control like the Asp.Net ScriptManager

Tags: asp.net

Maybe this is not the best title to it, but this is what I am trying to find out. I need a way to construct a control in ASP.Net that mimics the ScriptManager in that it should look like this:

```
<uc:MyControl Id="" ...>
  <MyListOfItems>
    <uc:Item someProperty="value1" someOtherProperty="value2" />
    <uc:Item someProperty="value3" someOtherProperty="value4" />
  </MyListOfItems>
</uc:MyControl>
```

How to make the Control have a List of items that you can add items to from the Source of a page.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you need to instruct your control to parse any inner content as subcontrols.  This is done using a couple attributes - [**ParseChildrenAttribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.parsechildrenattribute.aspx) and [**PersistChildrenAttribute**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.persistchildrenattribute.aspx) (if you want child controls to be maintained in ViewState).

1. Create a custom control that inherits from WebControl.
2. Add a `[ParseChildren(true, "MyListOfItems")]` attribute to your class.
3. Create a MyListOfItems property.